# folium marker popup shows the full html code rather than the pd.to_html() table (python - spyder)

Tags: python, html, pandas, folium

I have a def that is in fact an iter over the rows of a dataframe. when calling the def in the main program all data values are passed correctly however the resulted folium popup for each marker (note, markers are placed correctly in the map cluster) provides the full html code (having the correct values within the html tags) rather than a nice table supposed to be resulted by converting the dataframe into html. I would like to remove the html tags and have a table instead. I've searched all over but no luck on how to sort this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def plotInfected(ma,li,cl):

dat = pd.DataFrame(li)
dat = dat.dropna(subset=['lat','long'])

for index, row in dat.iterrows():
    dat1 = pd.DataFrame()
    dat1['ip'] = pd.Series(row['ip'])
    dat1['aso'] = pd.Series(row['aso'])
    dat1['protocol']=pd.Series(row['protocol'])


    html = dat1.to_html(classes="table table-striped table-hover table condensed table-responsive",index=False)
    popup = folium.Popup(html,parse_html=True)
    folium.Marker([row['lat'], row['long']], popup=popup,icon=folium.Icon(color='red',icon='info-sign')).add_to(cl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `parse_html=True` and that will do the magic